# converting word document file to chm file

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, chm

i want to convert doc file to chm file. i already used winChm to convert doc to chm,but winChm is not a free software.Is there any free doc to chm converter available?

Comment: You can check out NuHelp on sourceforge [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nuhelp/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should save your doc into HTML with Microsoft Word then using MS Help Workshop (free software) to convert it to a chm file.

Here is the link for the software : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21138

Comment: checkout nuhelp, it is constantly updated.